# Posts content not showing on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have been trying all I know in order to enable my site display post contents without success. Everything shows nicely on the activity stream but the posts and pages don’t show correctly. I tried editing the single.php and page.php files in the bp-themes folder but it still doesn’t correct it.
The website is www.relacc.com.ng

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later discovered this was due to the showposts(function) in the main index file. I had to look up the wordpress codex and learn the hard way :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have deleted the following code line in then `single.php` file:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Try to add it just after the `<?php the_title(); ?>` line and update the single.php file. This might solve the error.

Comment: It just wouldn't work. I have tried it in all sorts of manners and even removed the divs, but it still doesn't show. I just can't really understand the problem. I'm thinking of re-installing buddypress.